# How to draw circle for highlighted value in LineChart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello I want to ask how I can draw a circle for highlighted value in line chart swift. I am using Charts cocoa pods. I want to have a green circle appear when selecting a value from line chart view. I have this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MptKf.jpg, but I want this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd14z.jpg

```
class TappableLineChartView: LineChartView {

    public override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addTapRecognizer()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addTapRecognizer()
    }

    func addTapRecognizer() {
        let tapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chartTapped))
        tapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func chartTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            // show
            let position = sender.location(in: self)
            let highlight = self.getHighlightByTouchPoint(position)
            let dataSet = self.getDataSetByTouchPoint(point: position)
            dataSet?.drawValuesEnabled = true
            highlightValue(highlight)
        } else {
            // hide
            data?.dataSets.forEach{ $0.drawValuesEnabled = false }
            highlightValue(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply the code you have tried.

Comment: oh yes, I am new here sorry here it is

Comment: I tried with this to display the values when click, and then edit it but it is not working